# Grabbing data from firebase with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, http, firebase

I have the following code to grab data and view it in the console from a firebase setup, I have no idea why it isn't working. Here is my code below. It is running live at this [site](http://dev.anderskitson.ca) if you want to inspect it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc4J/) is a link to a jsfiddle

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="DemoApp">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.11/firebase.js'></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://edengarden.firebaseio.com/test');
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your web site is not available. I suggest setting up a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: its up now at dev.anderskitson.ca no port numbers i updated above. but js fiddle is a good idea.

Comment: Now I get a syntax error on http://dev.anderskitson.ca/arduino/public_html/. Just update the question when you have created the fiddle, we'll have a better chance of figuring it out.

Comment: Ok ive added the js fiddle link.

Comment: Your fiddle is listening for `child_added`, while the code in the question listens for `value`. Please make sure to have a single, consistent SCCE between them. But in general: listen for `value` on "regular" objects and listen for `child_added` when you have a list-like Firebase-ref, one that you `push` children to. I would recommend against mixing the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change your JavaScript to this:

```js
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://edengarden.firebaseio.com/test');
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    console.log(message);
});
```

It logs a lot of objects, like this:

> Object {value: 11}
>
> Object {value: 11}
>
> Object {value: 11}
>
> Object {value: 15}
>
> ...

Is that not what you see/expected?